# How Charts BarChartView Custom Adjusted

Tags: ios, swift, charts

Hi using cocoapods charts. Trying to pivot bar-chart from right to left. with hidden bottom x-axis values.

```
Charts
https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts
```

Below is code which I tried.

> ```
> totalExpenseAmount = 33 -> Double
> timesheetAmount = 300 -> Double
> ```

```
        self.setBarChart(expenseAmount: totalExpenseAmount, timesheetAmount: totalTimesheetAmount)
```

// MARK: - DRAW CHART

```
func setBarChart(expenseAmount: Double, timesheetAmount: Double){
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    for i in 0..<2 {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: i == 0 ? expenseAmount : timesheetAmount)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
    chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.init(hexString: "#008CA1") , UIColor.init(hexString: "#EF776C")]
    let chartData = BarChartData()
    chartData.barWidth = Double(0.25)
    chartData.append(chartDataSet)
    chartData.setDrawValues(true)
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.chartDescription.enabled = false
    barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    barChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    barChartView.data = chartData
    barChartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0
    barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

[image]

I tried to pivot bar chart from right to left. with Hidden bottom x-axis values.

Issue is second bar chart for 33 value not shown.
Unable to drawn bar chart from right to left.
Unable to hide the x-axis labels values ( -0.3 0.0 0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2 1.5)

Any one worked on charts please provide your inputs, Its deeply appreciated your input's.